# Regex restrict input in textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex, textbox

How do i restrict users to type only 4 numeric values in a textbox in asp.net? I need to use the regular expression validation please help

Comment: i don't know what to do, i am really novice in regular expressions

Comment: That's fair enough, but SO helpers are just that, helpers, they won't tend to do tasks in their entirety. Please have a look into some basic REGEX tutorials and attempt something, then we can help. [EDIT - @buring_LEGION has just completely blown me out of the water with an answer, so...]

Comment: sorry for a bad question (Maybe) i am new in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pete its very simple. in validation expression just type ^\d{4}$. you will be done.

Comment: where is validation expression?

Comment: how have you done so far? you got a textbox, and a regular expression validator on ur webform. right? in regular expression validation properties, find ValidationExpression and just typpe " ^\d{4}$ " without quotes and u'll be done

Comment: we can write our own regex too. For onfo visit [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for `asp.net`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />

   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
        ID="reg1" ValidationGroup="save" ControlToValidate="txt"
             ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$" ErrorMessage="Not 4 digits" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn" Text="Clicker" ValidationGroup="save" />
```

Comment: It would accept blank and four digits only, try it by entering any other than these values.

Answer (score 0):

if this regex is match `^\d{4}$` then user input only 4 digit

Comment: my regex match lonely 4 digit in string, if string contains something else regex does not match

Answer (score 0):

The below code validate from 0 digit to 4 digit. if you want exactly 4 digit then please follow burning_LEGION's example
    ^\d{0,4}$